# Take input from other widgets in a textfield in flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield

So I want to make a `TextField` in Flutter where user can input data from other widgets, I mean, the widgets are buttons containing numbers, and I want the user to input in the textfield using those buttons. How to do that? And also, how to disable the keyboard from popping up in case the user taps the textfield by mistake?

Comment: perhaps you are looking for something like this: https://pub.dev/packages/multiselect_formfield ?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: initialise TextEditingController

```
TextEditingController inputController = TextEditingController();
```

Step 2:

```
TextField(
    enabled: false,
controller: inputController, 
    ...
    ...
)
```

Step 3:

```
RaisedButton(
      color:  Colors.red,
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
         inputController.text = "Button 1";
        });
      },
      child: Text("Button 1"),
    )
```